# How to edit AutoCad coordinate drawing boundaries

Tags: autocad

How can I edit the Autodesk-AutoCad x and y coordinate surface? I would like it to have a larger coordinate boundary than the default...

Comment: 'limits' is the command in AutoCAD. Not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no limit to the coordinate boundary in autocad.
Just draw from here to infinity (and beyond).

Comment: At least with modern versions.  There might have been restrictions in the 80's or so.

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of CAD often would give you errors of drawing outside the limits. I found the LIMCHECK command would allow me to extend the limits of the drawing area. In newer versions of CAD though, this is not required.